# 3 (adjustable) column headline in Warsaw

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How can I adjust the following code to have a three column headline in the Warsaw theme. What I am trying to have is to get section, subsection and subsubsection show in each of the columns. Currently, the following code only shows sections and subsection. Thank you.

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.25\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.75\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Instead of just a short snippet it is usually more beneficial to post a compilable document (a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)).